# Pandas merge gives wrong output

Tags: python, pandas, merge

I noticed that in my code pandas merges the wrong corresponding row in my dataset, when I use merge on column that was calculated in pandas:
Here is my code:

```
df['rate'] = df['Nt_Rt'] - df['srvs_fee']
df = pd.merge(df, df1, on='rate', how='left')
```

The df dataset looks like this:

```
Nt_Rt       srvs_fee       rate

0.0275       0.0025         0.025
0.0325       0.0025         0.03
```

And the df1 dataset:

```
rate       P
0.025      103.453125
0.03       104.75
```

However, after merge the output is:

```
Nt_Rt       srvs_fee       rate          P
0.0275       0.0025         0.025    103.453125
0.0325       0.0025         0.03     103.453125
```

While for rate 0.3 it should be 104.75

Comment: You should post some basic code that shows this error with the actual data. In the past with this error I've had success by resetting the index of both dataframes before merging.

Comment: Unable to reproduce error.

Comment: I added the code and the actual data in my question: df['rate'] = df['Nt_Rt'] - df['srvs_fee']
df = pd.merge(df, df1, on='rate', how='left')

Answer (score 0):

I think pandas is rounding your "rate" column and treating 0.025 as 0.03 and giving you value 103.453125 for both records. Try converting your rate column to string and after merge convert back to decimal.

I shall try if there is any good approach.

Comment: the same issue. I tried it already :( no idea why. If I calculate column rate and after save the file and after read this csv file with calculated rate column before, then it merges without any issues. However, if I don't save after calculation column 'rate', then everything merged on rate '0.025'

Answer (score 0):

Floats are not great for joining on, particularly when one of the columns is computed.

```
>>> 0.0275 - 0.0025
0.025

>>> 0.0325 - 0.0025
0.030000000000000002
```

If I round the `df['rate']` column to 3 decimal places before the merge I get the right result.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Nt_Rt': [0.0275, 0.0325], 'srvs_fee': [0.0025, 0.0025]})
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'rate': [0.025, 0.03], 'P': [103.453125, 104.75]})

df['rate'] = df['Nt_Rt'] - df['srvs_fee']
df['rate'] = df['rate'].round(3)

df = df.merge(df1, on='rate', how='left')
print(df)
```

Output:

```
    Nt_Rt  srvs_fee   rate           P
0  0.0275    0.0025  0.025  103.453125
1  0.0325    0.0025  0.030  104.750000
```

You may need to keep more decimal places depending on other values. You may also need to round the `Nt_Rt` and `srvs_fee` columns before computing the `rate` column.